# From Database language to PHP

Tags: php, database

I need some help please. I have this from my database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    iwi.item Item, ppd.item_des Des, iwi.qty_on_hand QOH, iwi.qty_allocated QA, 
    iwi.qty_on_order QOO, iwi.min_qty Minimum, MAX(ppm.expected_date)Exp_Date
FROM inv_warehouse_items iwi, pur_po_master ppm, pur_po_detail ppd)
WHERE IWI.CO = '100'
AND iwi.item_key = ppd.item_key
AND ppm.po_key = ppd.po_key
AND iwi.warehouse = '01'
AND iwi.item IN ('BXHP335',
'BXHP435',
'BXHP535',
'BXHP644',
'BXHP743',
'BXHP965',
'BXHP10741',
'BXHP10748',
'BXHP1253',
'BXHP1257',
'BXHP121210',
'BXHP151410',
'BXHP16114',
'BXHP181411',
'BXHP241612',
'BX1195',
'BX6636',
'BXHP201512',
'BXHP1949',
'BXHP2015',
'BXHP201515',
'BXHP351011',
'BXHP241814',
'BXHP2257',
'BXHP1824')

GROUP BY iwi.item, iwi.qty_on_hand, iwi.qty_allocated, iwi.qty_on_order, 
     iwi.min_qty, ppd.item_des
ORDER BY iwi.item"
```

And I need it to print out with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be like this

```
$query = "...";
$result = $mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Why not using PDO? Better to start out the correct way, than having to relearn everything. At least that's my opinion.

Comment: @tcole, If OP is basic then It would be better if he follows progressive method.

Comment: @tcole he know mysql, not print in PHP

Comment: @GabrielSantos, not sure what print has to do with PDO? It seems he's got MySQL, but is new to PHP. PDO in my opinion would allow him to learn the correct way and not do a slow introduction that may stick with him down the road.

Comment: I know about the facilities of the PDO, but his question involves only the display of the content generated by the query, which Starx solved.